# How to specify location of the YAML configuration file for Dask-YARN

Tags: python, dask

Looking at [this](http://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html) page: the YARN configuration file `yarn.yaml` file needs to be placed in the locations `~/.config/dask/yarn.yaml` or `/etc/dask/yarn.yaml`. Can it also be placed in a location specified by the environment variable `DASK_ROOT_CONFIG` as mentioned [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#yaml-files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. All dask projects use the same configuration system and abide by the same environment variables.